# Inserting data into Database and Error in executeUpdate() method

Tags: java, mysql

```java
PreparedStatement ps;
String query = "INSERT INTO order (table_id,dish_id,price,count) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
try {
    con = DBHelper.getCon();
    ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setInt(1, order.getTable_id());
    ps.setInt(2, order.getDish_id());
    ps.setInt(3, order.getPrice());
    ps.setInt(4, order.getCount());
    result = ps.executeUpdate();
...
```

I have error in `executeUpdate()` method. It shows

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  error.

How can I fix it?

Comment: How did you create table ORDER? I tried and got an error. See this [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af1f54a144039f20f3906aa4fa5a2e3d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL statement, `order` is understood as the incomplete SQL keyword [ORDER BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp).

I would suggest you to rename the tablename to `orders` to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: According to your answer, it would be impossible to create table ORDER in the first place, wouldn't it?

Comment: I would suggest you to read and follow SQL naming conventions to avoid such discrepancies. It's not about being impossible, but defining everything in an unambiguous and absolute manner.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.It works.Now there is no error.

Comment: @EmilyWatson Why did you remove my accepted answer in the other thread? could you give me an upvote?

Comment: I am new user of Stackoverflow. Sorry. I will upvote.